# How many permutations are there for PARALLELOGRAM where the A's are separated?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In my book there is a permutation example question, the question is:

> How many permutations are there of the letters of the word PARALLELOGRAM? In how many of these are the A's separated?

I understood the solution for the first part of the question but for the second part they took the permutation of $10$ letters (omitting the A's) and they say that the A's have now to be placed on any $3$ of the available $11$ places, they take the combination of $3$ spaces from $11$ spaces and multiply it with the permutation of $10$ letters. what I don't understand is that from where does the $11$ spaces come from? I need some assistance.

Comment: Count the spaces in this particular permutation: `_P_R_L_L_E_L_O_G_R_M_`. Note there is one more spaces than there are letters between them.

Comment: @Theo Bendit- I couldn't get what you are trying to say. There are 11 spaces but why did you wrote them like that totally it is coming as 21 letters but there are only 13 letters

Comment: Sure, not all these spaces can be filled by the three $A$s. This doesn't matter though: you have $\binom{11}{3}$ places to put the $A$s, and you can just join up and ignore the remaining $8$ places, wherever they lie. For example, if I put $A$ in the first, third, and seventh positions, I would get `APRALLELAOGRM`.

Comment: @Theo Bendit- Thanks man, I understood it.  So there are 11 places between the letters in such a way that when you place A's in these places you end up having arrangements where the A's are separated. Well, what I thought is that When you place a 'A' in any arbitrary place then you can't place the other two A's in the either of the sides so by that reasoning there are 11 places. Can you say why my reasoning is not right? I don't understand why I thought this way.

Comment: As in, in a $13$ letter word, you've placed one $A$, and this eliminates $2$ places to put the other two $A$s, hence the number $11$? This reasoning just doesn't work; it's the result of looking for the number $11$, and taking the first reasonable-sounding explanation. Note: placing an $A$ first or last, for example, would only eliminate one position! And what about placing the third $A$ after the second has been placed? Your reasoning wouldn't extend to words with more than three $A$s either, e.g. `AMALGAMATE`.

Comment: @TheoBendit- I initially had the thought of 'what happens of i place the the A in the last or the first place?' , But i really didn't know what answer to give to my thought so i became a little uncertain and i posted my question here. Anyway Thanks man.